# Jquery UI resizable not working on empty contentedible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, contenteditable

I try to initialize the jquery ui resizable on a contenteditable div, but then I cannot edit the empty div content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" contenteditable=true></div>
  <script>
    $('div').resizable()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/wakowes

Answer (score 0):

Add a `&nbsp;` tag to the empty div and then it will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" contenteditable=true>&nbsp;</div>
  <script>
    $('div').resizable()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/dulelox